# Is there a way to query for database names within an SQLAnywhere Service?

Tags: sqlanywhere

I have launched an SQLAnywhere v12 service instance with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin64\dbsvc.exe" -as -s auto -t network
    -w TestEmpty12 "C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin64\dbsrv12.exe" 
    -n TestEmpty12 -x tcpip -c 512m 
    "C:\bin\Test Databases\Empty12\TestEmpty12.db"
```

I know that I can find running instances of SQLAnywhere using the dblocate executable. However, that utility only provides server name, address and port information. Is there a method in which I can get the database name, in this case 'TestEmpty12'?

Note that I am not necessarily on the same computer as the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run dblocate with the -d option. This will list database for each server as a comma-delimited list.

Documentation for dblocate:
[Server Enumeration utility (dblocate)](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbadmin/dblocate-server-dbutilities.html)